# php-fpm and apache after the user is modified, the access prompt does not have permission

Tags: php, apache, amazon-linux-2023

When I change the startup user for Apache and php-fpm, I get error 503 index.php access and Apache error

---

OS:Amazon linux 2023
Selinux: Enforcing
Apache version:2.48
php version:8.2
change to user:apps
groups:appsgrp

---

Folder:/var/local/app
Owner：apps:appsgrp

---

/etc/httpf/conf/httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 8443
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apps
Group appsgrp

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/local/app/httpd/html"


<Directory "/var/local/app/httpd">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/local/app/httpd/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"


LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/local/app/httpd/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>


<Directory "/var/local/app/httpd/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

---

I just changed the user and group fields in this file.

/etc/php-fpm.d/conf/www.conf

```
user apps
group appsgrp
```

---

error info

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tdLf.png)

I've tried to set the permissions of a lot of directories, but they still get errors, so I don't know where the problem is？